# How to change default log folder for pytest logging to custom using pytest.ini or yaml

Tags: python-3.x, logging, pytest

need help, 
I want to set up my logger from pytest.ini or using yaml file for this, all was good, except one thing:
folder for log file hardcoded in yaml or pytest.ini if use only file name, in this case, my log files save at a test folder, but I need to save my logs in my custom folder.

I don't want to overwrite my setup files.

method to read yaml file

```
with open(f'{get_root_path()}\logging.yaml', 'r') as f:
    config = yaml.safe_load(f.read())
    logging.config.dictConfig(config)
```

yaml

```
info_file_handler:
    class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
    level: INFO
    formatter: standard
    filename: folder info.log
    maxBytes: 10485760 # 10MB
    backupCount: 20
    encoding: utf8
```

pytest.ini

```
[pytest]
log_cli = 1
log_cli_level = DEBUG
log_cli_format = %(asctime)s [%(levelname)8s]  %(name)s  %(message)s (%(filename)s:%(lineno)s)

log_name = test
log_file = pytest.log
log_file_level = DEBUG
log_file_format = %(asctime)s [%(levelname)8s] %(message)s (%(filename)s:%(lineno)s)
log_file_date_format=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use logging `FileHandler` to achieve this.

Try to change your method to read yaml file as below:

```
with open(f'{get_root_path()}\logging.yaml', 'r') as f:
    config = yaml.safe_load(f.read())
    logging.config.dictConfig(config)
    current_log = logging.getLogger()
    fh = logging.FileHandler(os.path.join("you_folder_path", config["info_file_handler"]["filename"]))
    current_log.addHandler(fh)
```

Here, `config["info_file_handler"]["filename"]` would give you the same file name as in your yaml file. So this would create a same log file named as `folder info.log` but under custom folder. You can change the file name if you want.

So basically `FileHandler` defines a  file it is logging to.

Hope it would help !!